# Django Import Error Module "app1.context_processor" does not define a "songs_list" attribute/class

Tags: django

I have 2 apps in my django project, app1 and app2

app1/views.py

---

```
def list_view(request):
    songs = Song.objects.all()
    context = {
        'tracks_list' : songs
    }
    return render(request,"app1/list.html",context)
```

---

I want this list to appear on app2,

so I created a file called 'context_processor.py' inside app1:

---

```
from .models import Song

 def songs_list(request):
     songs = Song.objects.all()
     return {"songs_list":songs}
```

---

and inside settings.py I added this to the context_processors:

```
'app1.context_processor.songs_list',
```

---

And {{ songs_list }} to the templates

In the end I get an Import Error:

```
Module "app1.context_processor" does not define a "songs_list" attribute/class
```

---

Thank you for any help

Comment: file should be `context_processor.py`

Comment: thats what I have

Comment: I have reviewed your code, and it's correct. I'm pretty sure there is somewhere typo, one letter wrong, or you have file context_processor in inproper folder. Can you paste result of `tree` command of your project?

Comment: The context processor is in the same App that contains the model Song and has a view that renders the tracks_list on the template. 
Do I have to put the processor in the App where I want the list to appear and import the model from the first app? As in: from app1.models import Song ?